# chrome.tabs.executeScript shows unknown error

Tags: geolocation, google-chrome-extension

This is my code which I use for geolocation.

It does not log the coordinates to the console even though I have console.log. It shows an error saying **"chrome/ExtensionProcessBindings:95 Error during tabs.executeScript: Unknown error."** 
However, when asked to alert; it alerts the right coordinates

background.html

```
<script>
    chrome.tabs.executeScript(null, {file: "content_script.js"});
</script>
```

content_script.js

```
navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
 console.log(position.coords.latitude+" "+position.coords.longitude);
});
```

manifest.json

```
{
"name" : "Geolocation",
"version" : "0.1",
"background_page" : "background.html",
"permissions":["tabs","http://*/*", "https://*/*","*://*/*"]
}
```

Comment: Does it work if you inject content script through manifest?

Comment: Sorry, I dint understand what you mean. But i've edited my question with my manifest.json file too

Comment: In your manifest you are already injecting content_script.js to all pages automatically. If you want to inject it  on demand then remove `"content_scripts":...` from your manifest.

Comment: @serg : i edited the manifest with what you said. Is that right ?

Comment: @serg it still shows me the same error and along with that it doesn't even ask for the location permission when I load a page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code works fine for me.

I think the problem is that you are calling `chrome.tabs.executeScript()` right in the beginning of a background page, which means it probably tries to inject this script right into  `chrome://extensions/` when you are enabling your extension.

You need to make sure you are injecting the script to a regular loaded tab. For example I tried injecting it when a user clicks on browser action icon, and it worked:

```
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function() {
    chrome.tabs.executeScript(null, {file: "content_script.js"});
});
```

Comment: but my extension will be running in the background.It will be activated as soon as the user installs it, without any icon.

Comment: @user782400 Then you need to rethink your workflow. You can't inject content script immediately when extension is loaded because user can be on a wrong tab (and I am pretty sure injecting script wouldn't work on existing pages that were loaded before extension installation). You can create a `chrome.tabs.onUpdated` listener for example and inject your code once some tab is updated.

Comment: so, I tried the tab update, it asks for permission but returns the same error as before,ie.Error during tabs.executeScript: Unknown error. 

Is it a bug or something?

Comment: @user782400 Don't know, it runs fine on Chrome 13 (win beta) for me.

Comment: I get this all the time but I've never had any problems with it as it's never broken my script. I tried wrapping the injection with a `try...catch` block in my code but the error isn't managed that way so it still threw. Unless this is causing problems with your script and works on normal pages I would just leave it as I have.